# jQuery fadeIn() and fadeOUt() without delay

Tags: jquery, html, css, slideshow

Please see the attached JSFiddle.

Div1 (red) fades out to show div2 (blue). It all works fine. But there is a small time in between div1 fading out and div2 fading in when its all white. I understand it is because of the fade in code being inside the fadeOut completion.

Is there a way I can start the fadeout half way through the fade in. I have to do it with images, kinda mimic a slider.

I have tried using z-index on two  images and using a delay on the fadeIn, but that doesnt seem to work well. Its stacks the images one below the other. Not sure if I can use z-index with images

Any help is appreciated.

http://jsfiddle.net/nauy9zsg/

```
$('#div1').fadeIn();

setTimeout(function(){
    $('#div1').fadeToggle(600,function() {
       $('#div2').fadeToggle(600);
    });
},4000);
```

Comment: Is this what you want http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/nauy9zsg/2/?

Comment: @j08691: That is exactly what I am looking for. Can you please put it in the answers so I can mark it as one ? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to do what you're after. Fade out the first div and then after a short delay, fade in the second. Position them so that they sit on top of each other by using abolsute positioning:

```
$('#div1').fadeIn();
setTimeout(function () {
    $('#div1').fadeOut(600)
    setTimeout(function () {
        $('#div2').fadeToggle(600);
    }, 300);
}, 4000);
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/nauy9zsg/2/)**

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean you want one to blend into the other. You can use `position:absolute`. Here is my example http://jsfiddle.net/pgrillot/ywbgdgyL/

Answer (score 1):

is it this what you want to achive ?

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/rerxsu8p/)**

```
$('#div1').fadeIn();

setTimeout(function(){
    $('#div1').fadeToggle(600);
    $('#div2').fadeToggle(600);
},4000);
```

and css

```
#div1{
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    background-color:red;
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
}
```

if you want them div's overlayed use `position:absolute` or `relative`
may you add them to a container for better positioning.

you can also keep it going have a look at this

**[ANOTHER FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/9h6gb8ey/)**

Answer (score 0):

If you want the blue div to appear without delay, then remove the time delay (duration) from your fadeToggle method for div2 (blue div)

```
$('#div1').fadeIn();

setTimeout(function(){
    $('#div1').fadeToggle(600,function() {
       $('#div2').fadeToggle(0);
    });
},4000);
```

Here is the solution - http://jsfiddle.net/nauy9zsg/1/

Comment: The parameter of fadeToggle function is not delay, it's animation speed.

Comment: I do not think this is what I want. I am talking about the 'small' time in between the red and blue divs appering when the whole screen is white..

Answer (score 0):

Your issue falls with both div's not being able to be in a "fade state" at the same time. Otherwise one will appear below the other. The white that you're seeing is the initiation of the second div's fade, other wise you'd have something that looked like the two divs stacked for a split second. What are you attempting to use this for, there might be a better way to approach the way its being handled to allow a more smooth process.

Comment: Yeah, I am ok with having a stacked look for half a second. I want to mimic sort of a image slide show. Where one image fades to show the other one