# How can I fade in and fade out multiple elements?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I can get it to work with just one, but if I add multiple it fades them in and out at the same time (instead of one after another). Here's what I have tried:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
setTimeout(function(){
$("#head1").fadeToggle(1000);
}, 1200);
$("#head1").fadeToggle(1000);
setTimeout(function(){
$("#head2").fadeToggle(1000);
}, 1200);
$("#head2").fadeToggle(1000);
});
```

This fades them in and out at the same time. How can successive fading be achieved using jQuery?

Comment: Make a jsfiddle https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25211902/jquery-fadein-and-fadeout-without-delay

Comment: You might find [Queue & Dequeue](https://learn.jquery.com/effects/queue-and-dequeue-explained/) helpful. Also see [fadetoggle options](https://api.jquery.com/fadetoggle/#fadeToggle-options) and `done`: "A function to be called when the animation on an element completes". Here's an [example](https://api.jquery.com/fadetoggle/#entry-examples).

Answer (score 1):

You have to add up to the timeout duration like:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    
        var duration = 1200;
        setTimeout(function(){
        $("#head1").fadeToggle(1000);
        }, duration);
        $("#head1").fadeToggle(1000);//this will execute right away you will need another timeout
        setTimeout(function(){
        $("#head2").fadeToggle(1000);
        }, duration * 2);
        $("#head2").fadeToggle(1000);//this will execute right away you will need another timeout
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up coming across jQuery's .delay(). Here's what ended up working best:

```
$("#head1").delay(1000).fadeIn(1000).delay(500).fadeOut(1000);  
$("#head2").delay(3600).fadeIn(1000).delay(500).fadeOut(1000);
$("#head3").delay(6200).fadeIn(1000);
```

Comment: that's better & cleaner

Comment: Absolutely, thanks for your answer though! It could come in handy someday.

Comment: Now that is reusable! http://jsfiddle.net/tro34sbn/4/